# EF Core with MySQL connector incorrectly thinks utf8mb3 is in use

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-standard-2.0

I'm thoroughly perplexed as to why my project thinks utf8mb3 is being used. I'm running MariaDB 10.6.5

The configuration being passed is setup with a connection string that doesn't contain the CharSet, although it did but I removed it to see if it made a difference. CharSet=utf8mb4 was being passed. This is the default my.ini charset and collation

```
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

I had the database with no tables and it showed
[image]

I tried deleting the database and the CanConnect() call still complains about utf8mb3.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know where this mysterious utf8mb3 is coming from when it's actually utf8mb4?

I'm on EF Core 3.1.22 as this is a netstandard 2.0 project. I'm restricted to this as this is an addon mod resource for FiveM which doesn't support newer than netstandard2.0 for the server code. I'm using MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.22

The code is here [https://github.com/HTB-FiveM/nfive-htb/tree/features/nfive](https://github.com/HTB-FiveM/htb-rp/tree/features/nfive). You can run the one test in the integration tests project, probably need to have mariadb installed.

Comment: Almost everyone uses the truly open source MySqlConnector package instead of Oracle's MySql.Data. The open source package fixes a lot of bugs in MySQL.Data that Oracle has refused to fix. Including the faked "async" support. Try using `MySqlConnector` instead

Comment: Ok, so I referenced that as well as the Pomelo MySql Entity Framework Core package, not getting this "Could not load type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder' from assembly 'MySqlConnector, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d33d3e53aa5f8c92" with my context ``` public StorageContext() : base(
   new DbContextOptionsBuilder<StorageContext>()
    .UseMySql(ServerConfiguration.DatabaseConnection)
    .Options)```

Comment: I removed and re-added the Pomelo one only and it pulled in the dependency to to correct version of MySqlConnector and now I'm getting past that. Just need to sort out the migrations. Really weird that the Oracle one is THAT broken. Thanks so much

Comment: `Really weird that the Oracle one is THAT broken` not that weird once you realize Oracle has no reason to sabotage its cash cow (Oracle Database) by supporting not only a free database but a different platform and language. MySql.Data versions are only released when a new MySQL version is released. There are no interim fix or update versions. Even if you buy an Enterprise license, the money is peanuts and the "enterprise" support ... little better than a ticket system

Comment: It could be a lot worse. The Oracle .NET provider doesn't support async at all. It executes *synchronously* and returns the result wrapped in a `Task`. If you check the MySql.Data NuGet versions you'll notice a 2 year gap between 2016 and 2018